# How do I get my text and image panels to stay within my wrapper element when re-sizing the window in HTML?

Tags: html, css, anchor, containers, wrapper

When I try resizing my window the text and images seem to spill out of the wrapper element that I created. They are both inside of a container within the wrapper, yet they seem to continuously spill out into the next portion of white space. I need to find a way to keep them anchored to the blue wrapper element when the window is resized.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- Middle page grid content -->
    <div class="middle-grid">
        <h1>Features</h1>
        <p>Explore our extensive library of tools & features.</p>
        <p>Identify what works best for <strong>your</strong> needs.</p>
        <div id="wrapper">

            <div class="container">


                <a class="collab" href="#"><img src="http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h329/nicreed1/CollabTile_zpsuxqcjyau.png" height="30%" width="24%"style="margin:4% .3%"/> </a>


                <a class="plan" href="#"><img src="http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h329/nicreed1/PlanTile_zpsb4q2w1vv.png" height="30%" width="24%"style="margin:4% .3%"/> </a>


                <a class="recruit" href="#"><img src="http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h329/nicreed1/RecruitTile_zpsqdasla20.png" height="30%" width="24%"style="margin:4% .3%"/> </a>

                <a class="publish" href="#"><img src="http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h329/nicreed1/PublishTile_zpsagiliwn8.png" height="30%" width="24%"style="margin:4% .3%"/></a> 


                <a class="edit" href="#"><img src="http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h329/nicreed1/EditTile_zpswdstab8b.png" height="30%" width="24%"style="margin:2% .3%"/> </a>


                <a class="develop" href="#"><img src="http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h329/nicreed1/DevelopTile_zpscb6ydckr.png" height="30%" width="24%"style="margin:2% .3%"/> </a>


                <a class="create" href="#"><img src="http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h329/nicreed1/CreateTile_zpsc1y9ucff.png" height="30%" width="24%"style="margin:2% .3%"/> </a>

                <a class="manage" href="#"><img src="http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h329/nicreed1/ManageTile_zpsmlbfmznw.png" height="30%" width="24%"style="margin:2% .3%"/> </a>

                <p>Our options provide realistic solutions for realistic. Pricing is also competative, yet pallatable to even the the most earnest startup.</p>
                <p>Explore our library of options today and listen to testimonials <a href ="#" color="orange">HERE.</a></p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Then here is the CSS:

/*Middle Page Content*/

```
.middle-grid h1 {

    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 64px;

}
.middle-grid p {

    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height:90%;

}

#wrapper
{ 

    background-color:#34495e;
    height:90%;
    color: white;

}
.container { 

    width:100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;

}
.a {

    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;

}
```

Thanks a ton in advance for any help available!

Comment: I tried pasting your content into JSFiddle.net to sample it, but for the most part it seemed to display without issues. Can you make sure that you have all the code needed to reproduce the issue here? (You could use JSFiddle, or use the HTML/CSS/JS editor and preview feature in Stack Overflow's post editing toolbar)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ayvbwfLt/